# Connection to SQL Server database after restore

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, asp-classic, ado

I have been asked to maintain a site created in ASP classic that uses a SQL Server database.

I was given the database in the form of a backup. I restored the database on my local computer and created a `DSN connection` to it. However when I attempt to load my site, the `stored procedures` the site relies on give an error that execute permission was denied.

The stored procedures in question have a user named `UserSecure` showing as the only person with `EXECUTE` permission, I have tried creating a user by that name but that does not work, even though I can manually login to SQL Server Management Studio using `UserSecure` trying to connect from the web page using those credentials gives a `login failed error`.

If I run `sp_helplogins` my Windows credentials are shown as being owner of the database, and I can in fact execute from within SSMS but not from an ADO connection.

On another note the connection in the `webpage` was coded like this, I am not familiar with the application part of the connection. Perhaps this is part of the problem? I have tried connecting with a `DSN` and `DSN-less` connection and can connect but not do anything with the database?

Comment: Can you provide more context? What version of SQL? How many databases are invovled? Are there any cross-database references in your stored procedures or views?

Comment: Did you create a **user** in the database security or did you create a **login** under the server security?

Comment: What I ended up doing was instead of focusing on the one procedure I looked at the permissions for the entire DB and granted EXECUTE to the guest user. This is all being done on a local IIS for testing so security is not an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be the most elegent fix, but I quit focusing on the one procedure and instead granted execute permission to the guest user on the entire DB. Since this is only running on my personal machine security is not an issue and it seems to have fixed the problem.

Answer (score 4):

You should make sure the database server login is mapped to the appropriate database user (this problem crops up often when dealing with database backups). If it is not, then you need to fix the mapping. Fortunately, there is a command called `sp_change_users_login` that you can use to fix this problem.

First, check if your login is mapped to your database user. Using SQL Server Management Studio (assuming SQL Server 2008), look under Security/Logins for `UserSecure`. If you see it in the list, double click on it and select `User Mapping`. From there, locate the database you are trying to connect to, and see if `UserSecure` is mapped to that database. If it is not, you may be able to fix it using the following command (assuming `UserSecure` is the name of both the login **and** the user):

```
EXEC sp_change_users_login AUTO_FIX, UserSecure
```

See MSDN for more info on `sp_change_users_login`:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174378.aspx

Answer (score 0):

One issue that has bitten me a few times:

If your stored procedure (or view) requires permission from a user (let's say `userA`), and the stored procedure calls another database's table or view (say `viewB`), it is not sufficient to just make a login on `viewB`'s database, you must also explicitly grant `userA` permission to select/execute/etc. on `viewB` (which in turn requires a user on `viewB`'s database)

So in your case, you may need to explicitly grant `UserSecure` execute permission on a stored procedure on an existing database referenced by the one you restored.

Answer (score 0):

Know the problem all too well,

The ID of the user(name) will be different from the backed up database to the restored one. MSSQL stores the ID of the user and not the username (text), so the ID will be different (99% of the time) per machine and backup. So when the ID does not match you don't have access.

All you need to do is delete the user and recreate it, make sure you do it in both places:

Delete the user from the database first:

DATABASE -> SECURITY -> USERS -> Right click (username) + delete

Then goto

SECURITY -> LOGINS -> Right click (username) + delete

Then recreate the user and give the account the correct permissions and you're all good.